# How to dereference std::unique_ptr<int[]>?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++20, unique-ptr, dereference

The `operator*` works for `std::unique_ptr<std::array<int, 5>>` but not for `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`. But why?

Coming from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*):

> These member functions are only provided for unique_ptr for the single objects i.e. the primary template.

Here:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    // auto ptr { std::make_unique_for_overwrite<std::array<int, 5> >() };
    auto ptr{ std::make_unique_for_overwrite<int[]>(5) };
    if (ptr == nullptr) return 1;
    auto& out{ *ptr }; // does not compile for <int[]>
    std::ranges::transform(data, std::begin(out), std::negate{});

    for (const auto v : out)
        fmt::print("{} ", v);
    fmt::print("\n");
}
```

Error message:

```
<source>:16:17: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'std::unique_ptr<int [], std::default_delete<int []> >')
   16 |     auto& out { *ptr };
      |                 ^~~~
```

How can `out` be made bound to `int[5]` that is pointed to by `ptr`? I basically want to make the call to `transform` compile for the case of using a `std::unique_ptr< int[] > ptr;`.

One working solution that comes to my mind:

```
// ...
auto out{ ptr.get() };
std::ranges::transform(data, out, std::negate{});

for (const auto v : std::span{ out, 5 })
// ...
```

But is there another way of doing this without having to touch raw pointers?

Comment: Can you use [`[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_at)?

Comment: @Eljay With `std::transform`?

Comment: [`operator*() const`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*): equivalent to `*get()`.

Comment: What do you expect `operator*` applied on `std::unique_ptr< int[] >` to return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there another way of doing this without having to touch raw pointers?

Your current solution is far optimal in my opinion.

An alternative might be making a reference-range out of the `std::make_unique<int[]>` by calling the [`std::unique_ptr::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator_at) on each element.

```
#include <ranges>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> data{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
auto ptr{ std::make_unique<int[]>(5) };

auto range = std::views::iota(0u, std::size(data))
      | std::views::transform([&ptr](auto idx) -> int& { return ptr[idx]; });

std::ranges::transform(data, std::begin(range), std::negate{});

for (const auto v : range)
    std::cout << v;
```

[See live demo in godbolt.org](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/o7hcG4Pvb)